# How to handle Windows dialog boxes in Web UI automation?

Tags: c#, watin, ui-automation

I got stuck with the following problem. I am using WatiN with C# to automate the scenarios for Web UI application.

On a web page when I click on 'Print' button, a dialog window 'Save the file as' is opened where I need to enter a path and click on the Save button in the dialog box. When 'Print' button is clicked the browser will be keep on loading until I enter the path and save it through the dialog box.

What currently I did:

1. Using WatiN, I tried using WatiN.Core.Native.Windows class to get the Child window (Save the file as dialog dialog) - Parent would be the browser. When I tried using it, I found that there is no option to find the edit text box to send the path.

   ```
    System.IntPtr ptr = Utility.Browser.hWnd;
    WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window mainWin = new WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window(ptr);
    System.IntPtr childptr = WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.GetChildWindowHwnd(mainWin.Hwnd, "#32770"); // #32770 is the class name , retrieved from Inspect.exe.
   ```

   But always I am getting childptr as '0'.
2. Using UIAutomationClient, MS framework, below is my code.

   ```
   WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window windowMain = new  WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.Window(NativeMethods.GetWindow(ptr, 5)); // ptr as declared and initialized above
   TreeWalker trw = new TreeWalker(Condition.TrueCondition);
   AutomationElement mainWindow = trw.GetParent(AutomationElement.FromHandle(ptr));
   ```

   But i get stuck at the last line. I suspect that, it might be because the browser is loading in the background?
3. Using System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys,

   ```
   System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("path"); 
   // Gets stuck in above line after entering the path. Tried with only Send method, it says this method can not be used for this type of application.
   System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
   ```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with watin but I am familiar with C# ui automation using automation elements. I was able to get the save dialog from google chrome using this example.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AutomationElement aeDesktop = AutomationLibrary.GetDesktop();
            AutomationElement aeChrome =
                AutomationLibrary.GetAutomationElement(
                    "Gmail - Verify your Disqus.com account - Google Chrome", aeDesktop);
            List<AutomationElement> aeCollection = AutomationLibrary.GetAllAutomationElements(aeChrome);
            foreach (AutomationElement ae in aeCollection)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ae.Current.Name);
                if (ae.Current.Name == "Save As")
                {
                    List<AutomationElement> aeCollection2 = AutomationLibrary.GetAllAutomationElements(ae);
                    foreach (AutomationElement ae2 in aeCollection2)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ae2.Current.Name);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnableToFindAutomationElementException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The GetAutomationElement and GetAllAutomationElements are something I wrote to wrap all the treewalking you need to do with uiautomation. Here is the GetAllAutomationElement code which should be pretty easy to use for getting a single element if you need help with that. It took me a little while to figure out how I would retrieve all of them though.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all children elements of an automation element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aeElement"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<AutomationElement> GetAllAutomationElements(AutomationElement aeElement)
    {
        AutomationElement aeFirstChild = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(aeElement);

        List<AutomationElement> aeList = new List<AutomationElement>();
        aeList.Add(aeFirstChild);
        AutomationElement aeSibling = null;

        int count = 0;
        while ((aeSibling = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetNextSibling(aeList[count])) != null)
        {
            aeList.Add(aeSibling);
            count++;
        }

        return aeList;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I tried using the UI Automation as well (2nd resolution in my post). The issue I faced is that when the browser is still loading with the save as pop up shown, getting browser Window Pointer and its children (save as window dialog box) was hard :( and I was unable to find resolution for it. Anyhow it works fine if the browser is not loading (in another scenario).